# dataSet can read but props can't read

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-state

**This data can be read**

```
dataSet = [
        ["Gavin Cortez", "Team Leader", "San Francisco", "2860", "2008/10/26", "$235,500"],
        ["Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh", "8240", "2011/03/09", "$324,050"],
        ["Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2009/12/09", "$85,675"]
    ];
    render() {
        let data =this.state.data;
        console.log(data);
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <div className="tbl-mr">
                    <a href="/home" className="button1" > <u>Halaman Utama</u></a>
                    <a href="/tabel" className="button1" > <u>Tabel</u></a>
                    <a href="/datatable" className="button1" > <u>Data Tabel</u></a>
                    <a href="/karyawan" className="button1" > <u>Karyawan</u></a>
                    <a href="#" onClick={this.logout} className="logout">Logout</a>
                    <CobaData data={this.dataSet}  />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

But what I need is ** this.state.data ** to call mySQL data
the code above only reads local / in the dataSet
but I want to call all data in mySQL

```
 <CobaData data={this.state.data}  />
```

Comment: can you elaborate more what is the problem/ what you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to call data with this.props.data on child

but I can't, only with DataSet,

i need is to call data on mySQL

Comment: ok.. first off, there is no code for this.state.data, i assume this is what you want to get from your mysql. secondly, you said cannot read props in your title, i think it's just because there is data that you pass to <CobaData /> component. I think what you need to do is to get your data from your mysql database, normally this is done in separate project by using API, the front end can all the API using axios or fetch

Comment: if I use an ordinary table the data API can be called, but with datatables the data cannot be called

Comment: ??? where is the code to get the data from database?

Comment: for the post, get and others.... I call in the API,
to call the API I call 1 file with the code above

Comment: so yeah, depending on whether you use class based component, or function based component, you can either use componentDidMount or useEffect and call the api, and use setState to store the data from the api to your state

Comment: thank you for the comment, I'll try ^_^

Answer (score 0):

1. You will need a server side [API](https://medium.com/@onejohi/building-a-simple-rest-api-with-nodejs-and-express-da6273ed7ca9) in any language let say in [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/).
2. Your api will access your `MySQL`, you can get help from [Here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-nodejs/).
3. And finally your react application will call node api to get the MySQL data at client side.

You can have a complete picture from following links

- https://dev.to/kmaryam27/step-by-step-react-nodejs-and-mysql-simple-full-stack-application-2018-3ah0
- https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/create-a-react-frontend-a-node-express-backend-and-connect-them-together-c5798926047c/